# Proper way of referencing ranges of chapters

Tags: citations, citation-style

When I need to cite a range of pages in a source, I (well, LaTeX) write:

> See Smith (2010:30–34)

Similarly, when I need to reference a range of sections, I write:

> See Smith (2010:§§3.1–3.4)

For a reference of a single chapter:

> See Smith (2010:ch. 3)

But today, for the first time ever, I need to reference a range of chapters. What is the proper way of doing this? My first instinct was to go with

> See Smith (2010:chs. 3–6)

But then I realized that I had never seen *chs.* as an abbreviation of *chapters*, so I tried

> See Smith (2010:ch. 3-6)

Which is weird because it looks like I’m talking about just one chapter. And then

> See chapters 3 through 6 of Smith (2010)

Just looks unwieldy. So the questions are:

- Is there a convention for this particular type of citation?
- If not, what looks best to you, personally?

Comment: First of all, for ranges an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) (`--` in LaTeX) is preferred over a hyphen.

Comment: Yes, I know. Properly, what I write is `see \citet[31--34]{smith10}`, but I couldn't figure out how to render an en dash in the SE text field.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chs.) and a number of other sites, "chs." seems to be the appropriate pluralization of the "ch." abbreviation for chapters.  Note, however, that either is likely to be quite intelligible to a reader, and if the typesetters disagree with your choice, they'll surely fix it to their preferred style.  In short: just use "chs." and don't worry about it.